# Displaying array in tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Currently developing an app which has a list of all items in an existing array (which is in a separate .swift file). This is done by a tableView. However, I only get a empty tableview each time. Any idea what goes wrong?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

//Initialize the TableViewController
class CategoriesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

//Retrieve the array
var locationsAll = [Location]()

//Outlet
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

//Load view
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locationsAll.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "allCell")

    let location = locationsAll[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = location.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = location.rating

    return cell
    } 
}
```

As for the array, I've used a struct. The struct is called on MKMapView as well.

```
struct Location {
    let title: String
    let rating: String
    let description: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
}
```

The .swift file containing the struct & data:

```
struct Location {
        let title: String
        let rating: String
        let description: String
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double
    }

let locations = [
    Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111),
        Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111),
        Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111)
]
```

I call it in the file using `var locationsAll = [Location]()`
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You never add any elements to your array `locationsAll`

Comment: **which is in a separate .swift file**  ??

Comment: @Joakim Danielson How exactly do you mean? The array is already filled with data which I am looking to display through the tableView.

Comment: @Sh_Khan The array, called Location. Because there are several controllers which require the data that is inside the array.

Comment: that array doesn't look like filled with data, can you show us how and where do you fill it with data?

Comment: **locationsAll** is **let**  ==> `return locationsAll.count` so it can't be altered

Comment: The code doesn't display anything because the data source array `locationsAll` is a constant and is empty. Apart from that never *nil-coalesc* a standard table view cell, use the non-optional API: `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allCell", for: indexPath)`

Comment: @vadian How can the data source array be empty? If I check the file, it is filled with about 170 data items.

Comment: If you somehow have a global array (`Location`?) then you need to access that in your `CategoriesController` and not `locationsAll`. But can you really do that?

Comment: post that file , you use a separate array here , how you link to it

Comment: As mentioned by others, please add the code where the data source array is populated (it's **not** in the current code: **`var locationsAll = [Location]()` declares just an empty array**). And after populating the data source array you have to call `reloadData()` on the table view

Comment: Added the requested code. And now you mention it... @vadian I might have indeed declared a new **** array. Stupid... Completely missed that crap. Any idea how to use my filled one? If at all possible of course.

Comment: No, you create an empty array with `[Location]()`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So how else can one call an existing array?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! It did make me realise what I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you need

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return locations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "allCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "allCell")

    let location = locations[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = location.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = location.rating

    return cell
    } 
}
```

as it appears `let locations = [` is a global var so it's accessible everywhere , or you can declare

```
var locationsAll = [Location]()
```

then in `viewDidLoad`

```
locationsAll  = locations
```

Comment: It worked. How could I have missed to add in the style... Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's discouraged to use a global array as data source. Data is supposed to be encapsulated in a struct, class, or enum.

You could create the locations inside the controller.

Replace

```
var locationsAll = [Location]()
```

with

```
var locationsAll = [
    Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111),
    Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111),
    Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111)
]
```

Or declare the locations as **static** variable in the struct

```
struct Location {
    let title: String
    let rating: String
    let description: String
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double

    static let locations = [
        Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111),
        Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111),
        Location(title: "something", rating: "", description: "Old.", latitude: 10.11111, longitude: 1.11111)
    ]
}
```

and populate the data source array

```
var locationsAll = Location.locations
```

Comment: That is indeed better. I will adjust it in the code. Thank you!

Comment: I have however one problem now, I used a `for location in locations` loop to add annotations to my `mapView` but that gives an error which I can not resolve.

Comment: `locations` is a constant. Add the information to the objects in `locationsAll` in the controller.

Comment: Thanks a million! Code is better now.

Answer (score 0):

The count will equal 0. That’s why no cells are rendered.  after adding data you need to relodData on the table view.

I assume you set up the cell in a storyboard? Otherwise you need to register the cell before using.

Comment: Yes, I did do it through the storyboard. Gave it subtitle property and such. Also identifier. How can it be that the count will be 0?

Comment: There is no code adding data to the array. Or you add it after it’s ran and you need to dispatch a reload on the ui thread!

Comment: Thank you @msphn!