# How to display string array from Firebase in tableview?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

How to display the result of this firebase array in a table?
I can see the result in the console, but I would like to display in a table all the elements of the firebase array?

```
func getMaterie() {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("DegreeCourses").document(userInfo.Tipocorso)
    
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let materieArray = document.get("Materie") as? [[String: String]]
            print(materieArray!)
        }
    }
}

}
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrd1v.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying array in tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151985/displaying-array-in-tableview)

Comment: The question is a bit vague - a tableView is backed by a dataSource. In your case you would want to have a class var, `self.materieArray` instead of a local one. Once `self.materieArray` is populated, you would reload the tableView within the closure. Is there something more? Do you have some code that's not working?